# Threading performance degradation on Solaris 11 (sparc) using C++11 with GCC 4.8.0 and multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, solaris, sparc

I created a simple program to measure thread performance. I ripped out portions of a larger program in order to illustrate my point. Hopefully it's not too terrible to read.

Here is the program:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

std::mutex m_totalTranMutex;
int m_totalTrans = 0;
bool m_startThreads = false;
std::condition_variable m_allowThreadStart;
std::mutex m_threadStartMutex;
std::map<int,std::thread::native_handle_type> m_threadNativeHandles;

char *my_strdup(const char *str) 
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);

    char *x = (char *)malloc(len+1); 

    if(x == nullptr) 
        return nullptr; 

    memcpy(x,str,len+1);

    return x;
}


void DoWork()
{
    char abc[50000];
    char *s1, *s2;

    std::strcpy(abc, "12345");
    std::strcpy(abc+20000, "12345");

    s1 = my_strdup(abc);
    s2 = my_strdup(abc);

    free(s1);
    free(s2);
}

void WorkerThread(int threadID)
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_threadStartMutex);
        m_allowThreadStart.wait(lk, []{return m_startThreads;});
    }

    double transPerSec = 1 / 99999;
    int transactionCounter = 0;
    int64_t clockTicksUsed = 0;

    std::thread::native_handle_type handle = m_threadNativeHandles[threadID];

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point current = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end = start + std::chrono::minutes(1);

    int random_num_loops = 0;
    double interarrivaltime = 0.0;
    double timeHolderReal = 0.0;
    while(current < end)
    {
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startWork = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            for(int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < 100; ++loopIndex)
            {
                for(int alwaysOneHundred = 0; alwaysOneHundred < 100; ++alwaysOneHundred)
                {
                    DoWork();
                }
            }

            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endWork = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            ++transactionCounter;
            clockTicksUsed += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endWork - startWork).count();

        current = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> tranMutex(m_totalTranMutex);
    std::cout << "Thread " << threadID << " finished with  " << transactionCounter << " transaction." << std::endl;
    m_totalTrans += transactionCounter;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    int numthreads = atoi(argv[1]);

    std::list<std::thread> threads;

    int threadIds = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < numthreads; ++i)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(&WorkerThread, threadIds));
        m_threadNativeHandles.insert(std::make_pair(threadIds, threads.rbegin()->native_handle()));
        ++threadIds;
    }

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_threadStartMutex);
        m_startThreads = true;
    }

    m_allowThreadStart.notify_all();

    //Join until completion
    for(std::thread &th : threads)
    {
        th.join();
    }


    ss << "TotalTran" << std::endl
       << m_totalTrans << std::endl;

    std::cout << ss.str();

}
```

Application usage: app N
where app is the name of the application and N is the number of threads to produce. The program runs for 1 minute.

On windows, I build this program with Visual Studio 2012. I execute the program on a quad core I7 (4 cores, 2 threads per core).

I get the following:

```
simplethread 1
Thread 1 finished with  1667 transaction.
TotalTran
1667

simplethread 2
Thread 1 finished with  1037 transaction.
Thread 2 finished with  1030 transaction.
TotalTran
2067

simplethread 3
Thread 3 finished with  824 transaction.
Thread 2 finished with  830 transaction.
Thread 1 finished with  837 transaction.
TotalTran
2491

simplethread 4
Thread 3 finished with  688 transaction.
Thread 2 finished with  693 transaction.
Thread 1 finished with  704 transaction.
Thread 4 finished with  691 transaction.
TotalTran
2776

simplethread 8
Thread 2 finished with  334 transaction.
Thread 6 finished with  325 transaction.
Thread 7 finished with  346 transaction.
Thread 1 finished with  329 transaction.
Thread 8 finished with  329 transaction.
Thread 3 finished with  338 transaction.
Thread 5 finished with  331 transaction.
Thread 4 finished with  330 transaction.
TotalTran
2662

E:\Development\Projects\Applications\CPUBenchmark\Debug>simplethread 16
Thread 16 finished with  163 transaction.
Thread 15 finished with  169 transaction.
Thread 12 finished with  165 transaction.
Thread 9 finished with  170 transaction.
Thread 10 finished with  166 transaction.
Thread 4 finished with  164 transaction.
Thread 13 finished with  166 transaction.
Thread 8 finished with  165 transaction.
Thread 6 finished with  165 transaction.
Thread 5 finished with  168 transaction.
Thread 2 finished with  161 transaction.
Thread 1 finished with  159 transaction.
Thread 7 finished with  160 transaction.
Thread 11 finished with  161 transaction.
Thread 14 finished with  163 transaction.
Thread 3 finished with  161 transaction.
TotalTran
2626
```

These numbers look a little poor. I was expecting a lot closer to double going from one thread doing X work to 2 threads doing 2X work on this system. The threads did do about the same amount of work but not as much in one minutes time.

It get's even stranger when I move to solaris.

On Solaris 11, using GCC 4.8.0, I build this program as follows:

gcc -o simple simpleThreads.cpp -I. -std=c++11 -DSOLARIS=1 -lstdc++ -lm

when i run "./simple 1", i get

```
Thread 1 finished with  19686 transaction.
TotalTran
19686
```

for "./simple 2", I get:

```
Thread 1 finished with  5248 transaction.
Thread 2 finished with  2484 transaction.
TotalTran
7732
```

On Solaris, the 2 thread case is much slower. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to c++11 constructs and threads. So it's a double whammy. gcc -v shows the thread model is posix. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should at the very least turn optimizations on.

Comment: The `strcpy` and `memcpy` calls are copying only six characters, so the only significant work in this program is in the calls to `malloc`. Pounding `malloc` from multiple threads doesn't tell you much about thread performance.

Comment: I did turn optimizations on and regardless of the usefulness of the work. I'm still stumped at the results. If I run the program with 2 threads, I get the results above, If i run 2 parallel processes vs 1 process with 2 threads. I get the results I expect, each process doing about 20,000 transactions.

Comment: The malloc and free calls seem to be the cause of the off behavior on solaris. When I remove those calls and replace the variables with stack allocated equivalents, the behavior is as I expected. Running 2 threads gives similar performance to running 2 processes. I just don't know why.... (switching to new and delete didn't help either).

Comment: there are other implementations of malloc like `tcmalloc` and `jemalloc` that perform better for multi threaded applications. the problem origin is the locking in the malloc implementation.

Comment: To add to Alex's comment - the regular malloc library is a bad choice for threaded apps.  libmtmalloc is specifically meant for multithreading, for example.  All you have to do is to link against that lib.  Oh, and read the man page for libmtmalloc, there are loads of tuning choices.

Comment: On Solaris, re, malloc performance under contention (and options what to do about it / how to tune malloc behaviour), see this article: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mem-alloc-1557798.html